# HTML Form Pattern

Tags: html

How do I validate only when the first digit is 6,9 or 8 (currently allows 8 digits number)?

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="contactNumber" placeholder="8 Digits Contact Number"  pattern="[0-9]{8}" required="" name="contactnumber">
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this, edited

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="contactNumber" placeholder="8 Digits Contact Number"  pattern="/(6|8|9)\d{8}" required="" name="contactnumber">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

#### Your Required regex

```
/(6|9|8)\d{8}/
```

It starts by either looking for 6 or 9 or 8 and then followed by 8 digits.

#### Explanation

- 1st Capturing Group (6|9|8)
- 6 matches the character 6 literally (case sensitive)
- 9 matches the character 9 literally (case sensitive)
- 8 matches the character 8 literally (case sensitive)
- \d{9} matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

Comment: Hi @AndyAndy if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.